# throw er; event.js http.get with proxy

Tags: node.js, http

```
    var tabProxy = new Array(
    '122.72.76.122'
    ,'124.240.187.79'
     );
 http.get ({
            host: tabProxy[selectorProxy],
            port: 80,
            path: baseurl + counter
        }, function (response) {
            try{
                var statusCode = response.statusCode;
                console.log (statusCode);
             }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
```

with selectorProxy =0; it work
but with selectorProxy = 1; app crach :

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1417:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1513:23)
    at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:870:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

how to recup this error ( for extract this ip of my array ) ? 
the try catch doesn't work !!

Comment: Since you're happy with my answer, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your try/catch doesn't cover anything which would throw an error. More to the point, you need to listen for the `'error'` event on your request.

```
var req = http.get(options, function (res) { ... });
req.on('error', function (err) {
    //handle error here
});
```

Comment: @user1740962 please mark this answer correct since it solved your issue.